# How to lazy initialize generic List<T> via class extension

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to write safeAdd extention function for List class, so if it's not initialized yet - initialize it and add new value. But after I return from extension method, my just initialized list equals null. What's wrong?

Test class:

```
private class Test 
{
    public Test()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        //items = new List<string>();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> items { get; set; }
}
```

Extensions class:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static void safeAdd<T>(this List<T> list, T item)
    {
        if (list == null)
            list = new List<T>();
        list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Part of main:

```
Test t = new Test();
t.items.safeAdd("testWord");
//Here t.items == null; WHY?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have only assigned to a local method variable (which exists only inside the extension method) - this doesn't do anything to invoke the `set`, and to be honest there's no convenient way to get access to both the `get` and `set` without being verbose, or using lots of reflection / `Expression` code. IMO just do it in the class:

```
private List<string> items;
public List<string> Items { get {
     return items ?? (items = new List<string>()); } }
```

This will automatically initialize and assign the list the first time it is accessed.

It wouldn't be thread-safe unless I sync'd, or (perhaps preferable) used `Interocked.CompareExchange` for the assign. View     Interlocked
it could be made thread-safe easily enough, but this is rarely a requirement for instance methods, and **has associated overhead**

Comment: But not only `ValueTypes` are cloned in a method? I thought that we should use `ref` or `out` modifiers only for them..

Comment: @Jentor unless otherwise specified everything is passed by value including reference types where the reference is passed by value so change what the parameter point to do not change what the argument passed points to and you can't use ref this so no straight forward way around it

Comment: This method won't work for me. All that stuff is because I want to get rid of serialize overhead: if I serialize class where List == null, I'll get `{ "_id" : "07445fa8-5a51-414b-b0d6-590076af5f81" }`, otherwise, if List just empty: `{ "_id" : "82125e77-a52c-4dfa-afb7-a31560b10a9d", "items" : [] }`. But when I implement suggested method, my **items** List isn't serialized at all, either it was accessed or not.

Comment: @Jentor what serializer are you using? Many support the ShouldSerialize* pattern, I.e. `public bool ShouldSerializeItems() { return items != null; }`

Comment: Any reason for choosing ?? over Lazy<T> or just out of habit?

Comment: @MarcGravell Since I'm writing application that uses MongoDB, I'm using its native json serializer. And all that mess is because of `[BsonIgnoreIfNull]` Attribute.

Comment: @RuneFS because it does the job just fine

Comment: @Jentor there may be other options available depending on the serializer (callbacks etc), but another simple option: just manually init the list when needed. The only way to do it with an extension method would be very messy and awkward.

Comment: @RuneFS It seems that I just need to add a new method `addItem` in `Test` class where I'll check if my list is null. The reason of not choosing `Lazy` is because `Lazy<List>` object always not null, even its value wasn't used at all, so it is serialized anyway like `items" : []`

Comment: @MarcGravell Manually init list is an easiest way to do it. I just want to do it nice. :)

Comment: @Jentor "nice" here doesn't really exist unless you do it as a regular method on the type, rather than an extension method (a regular method would have access to the field)

Comment: the ?? based approach is as far as I can see from the IL not thread safe (Can't find documentation proving or disproving that though). In this particular case that's not really a question since List<T> instance members aren't thread safe either. My question was thus to see if there was similar arguments where ?? solves problems Lazy<T> creates that made you choose ?? over Lazy<T>

Comment: @RuneFS indeed, it wouldn't be thread-safe unless I sync'd, or (perhaps preferable) used `Interocked.CompareExchange` for the assign. View `Interlocked` it could be made thread-safe easily enough, but this is rarely a requirement for instance methods, and **has associated overhead**.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using .NET 4.0, you can use the [Lazy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) class to automatically handle lazy initialization. Your code then becomes:

```
private class Test 
{
    public Test()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        //items = new List<string>();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    private Lazy<List<string>> _items = new Lazy<List<string>>();
    public List<string> items 
    { 
        get { return _items.Value; }
    }
}
```

You can then call `Test.items.Add` at any time. It will be initialized on first use.

See [Lazy Initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286.aspx) for more information.

Comment: As I mentioned in previous answer, MongoDB C# driver will serialize `_items` object anyway, even it is empty. But I want to get all the charm of using `[BsonIgnoreIfNull]` Attribute.

Answer (score 0):

An more compact way using new C# features

```
private List<string> _items;
public List<string> Items
{
   get => _items ??= new();
   set => _items = value;
}
```